# BIOS Serial Number: Is it populated, constant and reliable

Tags: windows, winapi, bios

I intend to use the users BIOS/Motherboard Serial Number to uniquely identify a user. When I refer to the BIOS/Motherboard Serial Number I am referring to the number returned when you type in: `wmic BIOS get SerialNumber`

Regarding the BIOS/Motherboard' Serial Number:

- Can the user change this serial number? Either using third party applications or through Windows.
- According to this [forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/2bd70996-8dbf-4a96-85b0-341b9cf2ad74/wmic-uuid-returns-ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff?forum=ITCG), not all vendors supply a motherboard `UUID` so I cannot use this to uniquely identify the user. Do venders mostly/always supply/fill out the BIOS/Motherboard Serial Number or will I also find some computers dont have a serial number?
- I have tried to uniquely identify a user using the Hard Drive's Serial Number. But I have first hand run into the issue that it can change and that Windows API is unreliable and can return different values. See my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357514/can-why-does-a-hard-drive-serial-number-change). Do you know if I may experience the same issue for the BIOS/Motherboard's Serial Number?
- Can a standard process (Standard Windows User) retrieve the BIOS/Motherboard Serial Number? Or does the process need to be elevated (Admin User)?

Just to confirm the BIOS is the motherboard, correct? I am a little unclear because I thought the BIOS is the simple software installed on the motherboard.

Comment: *"I intend to use the users BIOS/Motherboard Serial Number to uniquely identify a user."* Now you have to make sure that a machine is used by a single user, and every user uses one machine only. You cannot ignore virtual machines either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, a power user can change nearly all serial numbers using either service utilities like AMI DMIEdit or by editing BIOS chip contents manually.
2. Most desktop motherboards right now are coming with empty MBSN and UUID, except for ASUS ones. The only PCs that almost always have valid identification data are branded ones (i.e. Dell or HP workstations).
3. Nearly all "individual" data can be changed somehow, and virtual devices makes the whole situation even more complex.
4. It depends on how you will try to access it, but general answer is "No, you need administrator rights". [Read more here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/6/5D6EAF2B-7DDF-476B-93DC-7CF0072878E6/SMBIOS.doc).

My 5 cents on this: just don't use HW-based identification, it brings more problems then solves.